# jquery mobile left menu

Tags: jquery-mobile, menu

Throughout the jQuery Mobile docs, they use a left-side menu for navigation that changes to a more mobile friendly version when the browser width is smaller. You can see an example on [this page.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)

They use this layout throughout the docs, and I can see in the source that they use two divs with the IDs "content-primary" and "content-secondary." My question relates to the fact that I can't find anything about this structure actually discussed in the documentation. It seems very strange that they would not include such a useful widget in the Framework. Did they use custom code to make this, or did I miss it in the documentation somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm frankly quite surprised to see how challenging it's been to find a left nav example that works consistently and as expected in JQM.

I wound up copying code directly from the JQM docs, including grabbing their custom .js and .css scripts (which defines the `.content-primary` and `.content-secondary` classes, as well as the various `@media` queries which make the menu responsive).

The JQM docs do not use the "multi-page" format.  Instead, each nav menu item links to a wholly separate URL (presumably prefetched into the DOM by adding `data-prefetch="true"` to the link), so each new page/URL must redefine the same nav menu over again.

This immediately makes my developer brain think "let's abstract the menu and include it on each page automatically".  But how to 'include' the menu on each page without PHP (or other server-side language)?  This is the problem I have yet to solve.

You may be able to call the `$(document).bind('pageinit',` function to manually inject your menu into the loading page by using javascript/jquery, but I have yet to figure out how to do this properly.

I'll keep you posted if/when I have a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not specific to jquery mobile, this is CSS3. You can check documentation here: http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/. Essentially what they do is specify style rules for different screen width using media query as shown in this example:

```
@media all and (min-width: 650px) { // you can define your width here
  // style rules here
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have a little experience with media queries, so I'm familiar with the concept. It just seemed a little silly to me that they created such an obviously useful widget to display their docs, but they didn't actually include the widget in the framework itself. Sure, I could just copy their HTML and CSS, but it just seemed a bit silly, so I thought I'd just make sure I wasn't missing anything first.

Comment: Actually, this is definitely a jQuery mobile specific issue - it's the JQM framework that makes left nav so difficult. There are a few plugins available, but I liked none of them.  Ultimately, while I have great respect for the jQuery guys, the whole framework feels too much like trying to put a square peg into a round hole.  So native it is, where I'm completely free.  Of course that's not without its caveats as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like the left menu at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html# ? Haven't played with it but it looks like these days it just takes

```
<div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal">
```