# jQuery Mobile menu

Tags: jquery-mobile, menu

This has been [asked for an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955458/jquery-mobile-left-menu), but no satisfying answer.

When viewed on small screen, [the jQuery Mobile doc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/) uses a multi-level menu panel that slides in when tapped.

[image: The menu button]
[image]

I tried copying the code but this is all I got:

[image]

Apparently you also need to specify `data-role="collapsible"` on `li`s with sub-menu, and some other attributes, which is not really ideal.

Surely there are people who use jQuery Mobile who also need the menu on their mobile website. But it is nowhere in the documentation.

Has anyone figured out how to do it without reinventing the wheel?
Or does jQuery Mobile simply not support this kind of menu without manually coding everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check *page source*, you will notice that `ul`s' within the panel have no `data-role="listview"` and `li`s' that contains sub-elements are given `data-role="collapsible"`.

That's not all, on `mobileinit` event, the aforementioned `ul`s' are converted into *listview* using the below code.

```
$(".jqm-navmenu-panel ul").listview();
```

Moreover, `padding` and `margin` are removed/modified on all panel's elements to get them stick to each others.

```
.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-listview > li .ui-collapsible-heading {
  margin: 0;
}

.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-collapsible.ui-li-static {
  padding: 0;
  border: none !important;
}

.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-collapsible + li > .ui-btn,
.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-collapsible + .ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading > .ui-btn,
.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-panel-inner > .ui-listview > li.ui-first-child .ui-btn {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-listview .ui-listview .ui-btn {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  color: #999;
}

.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-listview .ui-listview .ui-btn.ui-btn-active {
  color: #fff;
}

.jqm-navmenu-panel .ui-btn:after {
  opacity: .4;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=40);
}

.jqm-navmenu-panel ul li:first-child a{
  border-top: none;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Vr5JY/)**

Comment: Wow you're brilliant! Too bad jQuery Mobile doesn't make this part of the framework.

Comment: @aximili you're welcome! Normally in jQM you need to do some CSS job to achieve the look you want, so you need to get used to it ;)